# flutter_bloc. Automatically disposes cubit/bloc when used directly in BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

Does the code below automatically disposes the directly called instance (cubit in this case) if I called this directly.

```
BlocBuilder<TestCubit,TestState>(
  cubit: TestCubit(), // Direct call of cubit instance
  builder: (context,state){
     ....
  }
```

I'm wondering if the `BlocBuilder` will handle this directly. I don't need to use `BlocProvider` in this cubit/bloc neither want to use `StatefulWidget` just to call `dispose` method.

I have tried reading the flutter_bloc code implementations and its web documentation but I struggle to find an answer (or might just have missed it).

Hoping someone would enlighten me with this.